# how can import javafx into eclipse projects?

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, java-11

I´ve installed efxclipse to my eclipse ide. In the javafx settings i set the path to the javafx folder. But after creating a new javafx project, eclipse cannot find javafx. Do i have to import javafx as an "normal" library" or is there a way to include javafx automatically if I create a new javafx project?
I´m using openjdk 11 & openjfx 11

Comment: See documentation here: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-Eclipse. efxclipse doesn't install JavaFX.

Comment: In the linked page it is descriped for javafx 13. Is it the same for javafx 11?

Comment: Yes, it is the same for any JavaFX version starting on 11.

Comment: Is there also a way to include java fx without editing the vm-arguments